# Java: Prefix - Postfix issue

Tags: java, subtraction, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I have a small issue performing a subtraction on numbers using prefix and postfix operators.
This is my program:

```
public class postfixprefix  
{  
  public static void main (String args[])  
  {  
    int a = 5;  
    int b;  
    b = (a++) - (++a);  
    System.out.println("B = " +b);  
  }  
}
```

Doing this, theoretically I am supposed to get 0 as the answer, but however, I am getting a -2.

When I try to individually try to increment the values like in this program:

```
public class postfixprefix  
{  
  public static void main (String args[])  
  {  
    int a = 5;  
    int b, c;  
    b = a++;  
    c = ++a;  
    System.out.println("B = " +b);  
    System.out.println("C = " +c);  
  }  
}
```

I get the values as B = 5, C = 7.

So i get the idea that 'c' takes the value of 'a' from 'b' (Please correct me if i am wrong), but what I want to know is

1. How can I have it not take the value of 'a' from 'b', and
2. using  prefix - postfix, can I have 0 as an answer when they're subtracted.

Comment: Have you tried running `(++a) - (a++)` to see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b = a++;
means:

1. assign to b the value of a
2. increase a by 1

c = ++a
means:

1. increase a by 1
2. assign to c the value of a

b = (a++) - (++a)
means:

1. get the value of a (5) (a without the ++)
2. increase the value of a by 1 (thus making it 6) (the result of a++)
3. increase a by 1 (++a) (thus making it 7)
4. assign to b thae value 5-7=-2 (5 from step 1, 7 from step 3)

Answer (score 2):

If you go through this step by step, you can see what happens:

```
b = (a++) - (++a); //a is now 5
b = 5 - (++a);     //read a, then increment it. a is now 6
b = 5 - 7;         //increment a, then read it. a is now 7
b = -2
```

If you do it the other way, you get:

```
b = (++a) - (a++); //a is now 5
b = 6 - (a++);     //increment a, then read it. a is now 6
b = 6 - 6;         //read a, then increment it. a is now 7
b = 0
```

Comment: Nice explanation sir. +1 for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also tried "b = (a++) - (--a); " and got 0 as the answer. I understand the logic now.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 5;  
int b, c;  
b = a++;  
c = ++a;
```

About this code b has a value 5 because posting fix increment/decrement happens after assingment is completed. So the value is 5.

c has a value 7 because prefix increment/decrement happens before assingment is completed. So the value is 7 beause previous statement made the value of a as 6.

About this code

```
int a = 5;  
int b;  
b = (a++) - (++a);  
System.out.println("B = " +b);
```

when brackets are applied, your prefix/postfix operations will be completed first in `(a++) - (++a);` from left to right fashion.

So firstly if we go left to right

```
(a++) -(++a)
1. (a++) -- Take 5 from a.
2. (++a) -- 5 becomes 6 with ++a take 6.
3. (a++) - (++a) -- Subtract results of (a++) - (++a) operations which makes it -2.
```

**Solutions for you first query** -- *How can I have it not take the value of 'a' from 'b', and*

```
int a = 5; 
int temp = a; 
int b, c;  
b = a++;  
c = ++temp;  
System.out.println("B = " +b);  
System.out.println("C = " +c);
```

**Solutions for you first query has been well explained by Sir *@Keppil* **

Comment: Yup.. it has. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

> So i get the idea that 'c' takes the value of 'a' from 'b' (Please correct me if i am wrong), but what I want to know is 1) How can I have it not take the value of 'a' from 'b'

Its not like this, in `c = ++a;` value is taken from a only, in `b = a++;` statement, a was incremented but after assigning value to b, and  then while `c = ++a;` a is again incremented and assigned to c (as this is pre-increment now)

> 2) using prefix - postfix, can I have 0 as an answer when they're subtracted.

you can have like: `b = (++a) - (a++);` as first a increments first and then the second a (which is now 6) is substracted from first a (still 6). And then the final value of a is 7

Comment: Thank you very much for answering this. I get the logic now :)