# Difference between int and Integer

Tags: java, integer, int, wrapper, primitive-types

What is the difference between `int` and `Integer`. Yes, one is `primitive` and another one is `wrapper`, what is the situation to use them correctly.

Also what is the difference between :

```
int i=0;
++i
and 
i++
```

Comment: `++i` is prefix incrementor, which adds 1 to `i` and returns the new value. `i++` is postfix incrementor, which returns the value of `i` and then adds 1 to `i`.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460879/java-prefix-postfix-issue/16461035 for the ++i and i++

Comment: Ask two different things int two different questions. And make the title descriptive.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570416/when-to-use-wrapper-class-and-primitive-type for the primitive vs wrapper question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**part 1**

One example .. you can use `Integer` as the key of `HashMap` but you can't use int. Because an `Object` is needed.

So where you need an `int` value as an object there you need to use `Integer` class.

**part 2**

++i is pre increment
i++ is post increment

for example

```
i = 0;
System.out.println(i++) //will print 0 then the i will be 1.
```

and

```
i = 0;
System.out.println(++i) // here i wil be incremented first then print 1.
```

Answer (score 3):

`Integer` is a wrapper class for `int` which is a primitive data type. `Integer` is used when `int` can't suffice. For example: In generics, the type of the generic class, method or variable cannot accept a primitive data type. In that case `Integer` comes to rescue.

```
List<int> list;   //Doesn't compiles
List<Integer> list;  // Compiles
```

Moreover `Integer` comes with a plethora of static methods, like `toBinaryString`, `toHexString`, `numberOfLeadingZeros`, etc. which can come in very handy.

Answer (score 3):

As already explained above 
  An Integer is an object, whereas an int is a primitive. So you can have a null reference to an Integer and a Set or List of them. You can not do that with an int

I find this null reference very useful, when i have to store int values in database. I can store a null value when I use Integer. But cannot do so when I use int.

Answer (score 1):

An `Integer` is an object, whereas an `int` is a primitive.  So you can have  a null reference to an `Integer` and a `Set` or `List` of them. You can not do that with an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

A basic explanation is an `int` is a primitive data type and literally is only a value stored in memory. An `Integer` is a Java object that wraps an `int` in a Class with lots of nice/helpful methods that can be called to work with that backing `int` hidden inside. This is the same with most of the primitive data types, such as `boolean` and `Boolean`, `char` and `Character`, etc. This is refereed to as `Boxing` a primitive. Unboxing being the opposite, taking an Object and extracting the backing primative.

Here's an example of how one may use `Integer` to convert a `String` into an `int` (boxed to an `Integer`)

```
String someString = "10";
Integer intObj = Integer.parseInt(someString);
System.out.println(intObj.toString());
```

You'll find that some of the data types have more helpful methods than others. Check the JavaDoc's for each of the types you are interested in, there are a lot of goodies in there!